# Not open NSWindow has isVisible property set to true

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to detect if `NSWindow` is open or closed using the `isVisible` property of `NSWindow`, but it is not working as I expected. For example I overrode the `loadWindow` method of my `NSWindowController` (I need to show a fullscreen web on the extended screen):

```
override func loadWindow() {
    self.contentController = WKUserContentController();

    guard let contentController = self.contentController else {
        return
    }

    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.userContentController = contentController


    let externalScreens = NSScreen.externalScreens()
    let screen = externalScreens.count == 0 ? NSScreen.main()! : externalScreens[0]

    window = KeyWindow(
        contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screen.frame.width, height: screen.frame.height),
        styleMask: NSBorderlessWindowMask,
        backing: NSBackingStoreType.buffered,
        defer: false,
        screen: screen
    )

    if let w = window {
        w.level = Int(CGShieldingWindowLevel())
        w.backgroundColor = NSColor.black
        w.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
        w.makeFirstResponder(self)

        webView = WKWebView(frame: w.frame, configuration: config)
        w.contentView = webView!

        debugPrint("Window is visible = \(w.isVisible)")
    }
}
```

KeyWindow:

```
import Foundation
import AppKit

class KeyWindow : NSWindow {
    override var canBecomeKey: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

but debugPrint shows that `isVisible` property is set to true, although the window was not opened yet (`self.showWindow(self)` method of controller was not called yet).

How can I reliably find out if window is open (displayed on screen) or not?

Comment: ` w.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)` should actually "open" the Window

Comment: hm, but it is not visible on screen until I call `showWindow`

Comment: I think here is your problem then :-) you are using shieldWindowLevel, it maybe covered by another shieldWindowlevel like this??
try to call    ` [w makeKeyWindow]; ` and then ` [w orderFrontRegardless];`

Comment: I tried to omit the `makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)` line - `isVisible` is now set to false, but first calling of `showWindow` now takes much more time to show/render the window - that is why I had `makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)` in `loadWindow` (it seems that the window was "prerendered" on backround).

Comment: Sometimes orderFrontSelf -doesn't work as expected - So I tend to orderFront regardless - especially when working with such a window level.

Answer (score 0):

in your code

```
if let w = window {
    w.level = Int(CGShieldingWindowLevel())
    w.backgroundColor = NSColor.black
    w.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
    w.makeFirstResponder(self)

    webView = WKWebView(frame: w.frame, configuration: config)
    w.contentView = webView!

    debugPrint("Window is visible = \(w.isVisible)")
}
```

you are calling `w.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)` before the check 
according to the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nswindow):

> func makeKeyAndOrderFront(Any?) Moves the window to the front of the
>   screen list, within its level, and makes it the key window; that is,
>   it shows the window.

So technically the `isVisible` works as advertised :)
[isVisible](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nswindow/1419132-isvisible)

> The value of this property is true when the window is onscreen (even
>   if it’s obscured by other windows); otherwise, false.

You window should be onscreen  - despite the fact that you have set it's level as `CGShieldingWindowLevel` it maybe just invisible due to call of
`w.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)` you can try to call `func orderFrontRegardless()`

[Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nswindow/1419444-orderfrontregardless)

In this case it shall show the window immediately - but I think it is another SO Question